# Create dynamic android activities

Tags: java, android, mysql, dynamic

I am trying to create an android app that has multiple "pages" ,
for example : you can choose any city in the world (e.g : Rome,Berlin,New york..), and by click on it you move to the specific city activity and get specific information, such as: country, nubmer of people.. etc (All the categories are the same, and the information changes for each city )

the specific information should be stored on mySQL database

I would like to ask - how can i implement this on an android application?

thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look like you've tried anything. Have you?

Comment: I don't get the problem. What have you done and what problems have you faced?

Answer (score 0):

You have to open a new Activity (CityActivity) adding the selected city to the Intent:

```
Intent cityIntent = new Intent(this, CityActivity.class);
cityIntent.putExtra("city", selectedCity);
startActivity(cityIntent);
```

Then in City activity you have to get the value that you sent via Intent:

```
String city = getIntent().getStringExtra("city");
```

Now you are able to get the information of the corresponding city and draw the information in a common view.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Fragment` instead. just create a dynamic fragment that runs on one activity. its can handle almost anything an activity can handle.

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

[Click Here on how to create Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)